# Find index of first element not equal to a specific value

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, find

I want to find the index of the first element in a string that is not equal to a given value

Pseudo code:

```
string='111111234131986'
string.find(!='1')
```

Result:

```
6
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. In your example, there's plenty more elements not equal to '1' in your string. Do you want to match only the last element?

Comment: simply invert find logic in not find logic

Comment: No I think he wants the first element index value. It's confusing here because that's the same as the last digit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a very simple solution using [`lstrip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip) and [`len()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len):

```
len(string) - len(string.lstrip("1"))
```

This solution returns `len(string)` if `string` is empty or entirely composed by "1"s.

Comment: @bcosta12 '231451' return 0 and that's what I expect.

Comment: In the first solution, if string is empty or entirely composed by "1"s, i obtain an index out of range exception. Regardless of this, the second solution is better for my necessity.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you want the first element that isn't `'1'`, we can use [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) and [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)

```
>>> string='111111234131986'
>>> next((i for i, x in enumerate(string) if x!='1'), None)
6
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try this,

```py
string='111111234131986' #required string
for items in string: #loop to iterate over the elements to find the odd one
    if items != '1':
       print items

Output for this:
2
3
4
3
9
8
6
```